# Tomcat creates excessive output at webapp startup

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Please see the solution below, the error description is a bit fuzzy since did not have any idea what was wrong.

I am trying to deploy a new tomcat7 on linux, for later the whole machine to be cloned, so would like to set it up properly now. Tomcat itsel starts up properly, but when trying to deploy our application by copying the war file into the webapps dir, the catalina error out file is flooded by about 50MB of FINE logging (see a portion of it below), and nothing is put into the normal output file, and the normal log file.

The same does not happen with the sample.war file provided with the tomcat docs (\appdev\sample\sample.war), it starts up with the usual some lines of log.

The logging.properties file is the default one with every 'FINE' replaced with 'INFO', and every other tomcat file is also unmodified.

What *is* customized: the tomcat is run with jsvc and a customized startup script. `CATALINA_BASE` is separated from `CATALINA_HOME` and tomcat is run with a non-root user. EDIT: not sure if matters, but the startup script sets these startup parameters regarding logging: `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<logging.proprties' path> 
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager` and also the console out and console out error are set up by the startup script.

Most of the error file's content comes from the class `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester` and seems harmless FINE level log.

There are no SEVERE, ERROR logs, and there's one WARNING regarding some unset locale, and this one below, but they are almost at the end of the log:

```
Jul 31, 2013 12:34:24 PM org.apache.myfaces.component.html.util.ExtensionsFilter <init>
WARNING: Please adjust your web.xml to use org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter
```

The logging.properties looks like this now:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.[Catalina].handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

---

EDIT2: added facility specific properties for `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester` but no success

---

Why does the log go to the outfile, and not into the log file? The sample.war's log goes to both, but it's only some lines per start/stop.
Regardless of the destination, why is there any FINE logging, when everything is set to INFO?

So please kindly adwise what I might be doing wrong. I can get the source of the application and check and maybe modify stuff in it, but I am not aware of it's internals. Even if there are errors in it, I don't think this error output file should be this large, and logging should work properly with the default config.

Comment: EDIT: turned out, that the tomcat startup script did not set up the error output file. After setting it up, all the fine logging goes to it, and none of excessive logging goes either to the normal outfile or the logfile. Edited this in the original post.

Comment: EDIT2: added added facility specific properties for `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester` but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution comes from Mustafa Yuksel, described [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.tomcat.user/216425). The guy is a hero, we had the exact same issues and we couldn't figure them out in weeks.

The first issue was that the war file does not use `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester`, it was in fact the `org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.level` class which used the wrong logger. So that you can mask the FINE logging with the line

```
org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.level = INFO
```

The second issue was that we had a logging.properties in a project, that we had Eclipse include in our war files. That project included an additional logging.properties file which we had no idea about. Included eclipse projects are present as jar files in /WEB-INF/lib/ so you have to dig into those.